# Datetime-local height offset on ios

Tags: jquery, html, css, datetime

I am implementing in a datetime-local textbox on my website that is used by my mobile phone. However, with the datetime-local it appears to set the textbox higher than the rest of the textboxes on the row? As you can see from the image the departure (datetime-local) is higher than the normal textbox causing the offset to look extremely weird. What I am looking for is a way to reset the height offset so that it appears in line with the rest of the textboxes.

Comment: I am not sure why I got a downvote... however I did solve my own problem on iphone and android datetime-local vertical-align is set to top... reset using vertical-align:bottom; and it will align normal

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten this solved myself and for anyone using the html5 version of the mobile datetimepickers this should help:

On iphone and android datetime-local vertical-align is set to top... reset using vertical-align:bottom; and it will align with the rest of your textboxes on your page.